# Value getting dropped too early inside closure and combinator while borrow exists

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, borrow-checker, combinators

I'm facing a problem with a value being dropped while it is still borrowed inside an `Option`, in a closure, but I'm having a hard time grasping exactly what's going on. To illustrate, here is a working example of what I'm actually trying to achieve:

```
fn foo() -> Option<String> {
    let hd = match std::env::home_dir() {                                       
        Some(d) => d,                                                           
        None => return None,                                                    
    };                                                                          
    let fi = match hd.file_name() {                                             
        Some(f) => f,                                                           
        None => return None,                                                    
    };                                                                          
    let st = match fi.to_str() {                                                
        Some(s) => s,                                                           
        None => return None,                                                    
    };                                                                          
    Some(String::from(st))  
}
```

The return value is the base name of the current user's home directory inside `Option<String>`.

I thought I'd try refactoring this with combinators to get rid of the lines `None => return None,`.

```
std::env::home_dir()                                                        
    .and_then(|d| d.file_name())                                            
    .and_then(|f| f.to_str())                                               
    .map(String::from)
```

But rustc detects a reference that outlives its value.

```
error: `d` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:33:35
   |
33 |         .and_then(|d| d.file_name())
   |                       -           ^ `d` dropped here while still borrowed
   |                       |
   |                       borrow occurs here
34 |         .and_then(|f| f.to_str())
35 |         .map(String::from)
   |                          - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

I **think** this is because the reference in `Option<&OsStr>` is outliving the value of type `PathBuf`. However I'm still having a hard time figuring out how to approach this without having the value go out of scope too soon.

To further illustrate what I'm trying to achieve, here is a similar example with a type that implements the Copy trait.

```
let x = 42u16.checked_add(1234)                                             
    .and_then(|i| i.checked_add(5678))                                      
    .and_then(|i| i.checked_sub(90))                                        
    .map(|i| i.to_string());                                                
println!("{:?}", x); // Some("6864")
```

So I'm definitely overlooking a few things related to ownership in the prior example. Is this possible with `Option<PathBuf>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that you're consuming the `PathBuf` returned from `home_dir()` but still trying to use references.

I would keep it in a variable, and work from there:

```
fn foo() -> Option<String> {
    let path = std::env::home_dir();
    path.as_ref()
        .and_then(|d| d.file_name())
        .and_then(|f| f.to_str())
        .map(String::from)

}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0a11ebb370b4e6a154d7115690ae1ac2&version=stable&backtrace=0))

The call to `path.as_ref()` makes an `Option<&PathBuf>` as the starting point for the chain of `and_then`, without consuming the original owned `PathBuf` which is needed at least until `String::from`.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Chris's answer: You can also fix the issue by nesting the chain starting from the second `and_then` into the closure passed to the first `and_then`. This works because it keeps `d` (which owns a `PathBuf`) alive until the borrows on it are released.

```
fn foo() -> Option<String> {
    std::env::home_dir().and_then(|d| {
        d.file_name()
           .and_then(|f| f.to_str())
           .map(String::from)
    })
}
```